# Set connectionTimeouts and socketTimeouts in Spring CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using the Spring AMQP library .How do I configure connectionTimeouts and socketTimeouts in CachingConnectionFactory.I assume it must internally use
http://www.rabbitmq.com/javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html#setConnectionTimeout(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an [open JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-391) to expose some more of these attributes, which should be in the next releease.

In the meantime, you can wire up a Rabbit `ConnectionFactory` and provide it to the `CachingConnectionFactory` - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e354).